SSH to server and run script in background
Problem
I am trying to ssh to an ec2 instance and run my python script in the background so as to detach it from the SSH session. Here is the command I am trying at the moment:
ssh -i {key} -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -q ec2-user@{ip} /bin/sh -c 'nohup env/bin/python main.py > log.out &'
which results in the following error:
nohup: missing operand
What I've tried
I can ssh to the server first, then run the /bin/sh -c ... command and it works fine. Does nohup require different ssh arguments to work properly?
local$ ssh ec2-user@{ip}
...
remote$ /bin/sh -c 'nohup env/bin/python main.py > log.out &'


You might be in a different path by default? Try converting env/bin/python into a full path (eg /user/ec2-user/env/bin/python)?

What happens if you do not use sh -c but just run nohup ...?

See this post for more details, but the short version is you should run something like ssh -i {key} -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -q ec2-user@{ip} '/bin/sh -c "nohup env/bin/python main.py > log.out &"' 

Adding quotes around the whole command resulted in the python command entering a zombie state and the ssh session did not detach (I have no idea why). If I don't use sh -c, the output redirection happens locally. Providing the absolute path of the python binary didn't help either.

The following command worked:
ssh -i {key} -o {opts} -nf ec2-user@{ip} "nohup env/bin/python main.py > log.out &"
After considering Anon and Yuri's comments, I realized I probably didn't need the extra sh -c call. The only changes made to the original command are:

-nf option
Detaches the SSH session after launching the command

"nohup ... &"
Quote the whole command so it safely passed to the remote shell


